# Got a rejection email, however later I was sent an interview email

Tags: interviewing, united-states, rejection

Applied for a company a month ago. Did an assessment test followed by a webcam recorded interview. A week later I got the generic `we are pursuing other candidates` rejection email. Well, forward three weeks later and they have contacted me with a call, text messages, and emails wanting me to attend a two day interview.

Does this happen a lot and should I be weary?

**I never interviewed with the company so this is not the same as going through the interview, getting rejection and than getting a offer/interview email.**

Comment: Is this a recruiting company of some sort or an employer? Do you know how big is the company?

Comment: @WorkerWithoutACause I don't agree with that duplicate, the ordering of the contact emails is wrong to make this question a duplicate too

Comment: You're experience is somewhat uncommon, but not too rare.  I would not be weary; just move forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can do, though it shows some things could have happened:

1. They re-reviewed the candidates and wanted to select you. Possibly
   due to their favourite dropping out, however this shows incompetence
   for not waiting before doing the rejection
2. They made a mistake in sending the first email out, again shows possible incompetence
3. The interview e-mail was sent to you by mistake

Either way, they've made a mistake somehow and it's now up to you to confirm which email was the mistake one. Contact them, see what they say and then you can decide if you wish to go to the interview.

Remember, they have made a mistake, so this could happen often, is that something you want to work for? Check your previous communications for any similar problems as well.

Comment: You might be right. The company was recently bought by [Berkshire Hathaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkshire_Hathaway) and is expanding rapidly.

Comment: It may not be a mistake.  They could have had circumstances change significantly within those three weeks.  Perhaps they now need to hire many more people.  Or maybe someone accepted the job offer only to pull out later.  It's not "incompetence" to tell people they are no longer being considered as soon as you're reasonably sure they're out of the running; it's common courtesy.

Answer (score 2):

The "other candidates" mentioned likely fell through and they couldn't retain them. This is a very common occurrence.

If there is nothing else that caused you concerns, I would not worry too much. However, two full days of interviewing seems questionable.

Comment: Yeah it is excessive. First day is from 1pm-6pm where they do individual interviews and basically talk about the company, presentations, etc..   Second day is a group panel interview and lasts 4 hours followed by IQ test, assessment test, behavior test, and drug test.  Wouldn't be surprised if they asked for fingerprints lol

Comment: Well, depends on the interviews, and depends on the job. It's excessive for a burger-flipping position. It's not for the position of a country manager of a touchy national branch showing a lot of specific problems.